# How to override vendor class file?

Tags: laravel, overriding

My laravel version : 5.2

I want to override tymondesigns/jwt-auth GetUserFromToken.php

```
\vendor\tymon\jwt-auth\src\Middleware\GetUserFromToken.php

    class GetUserFromToken extends BaseMiddleware
    {
        /**
         * Handle an incoming request.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Closure  $next
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
        {
            if (! $token = $this->auth->setRequest($request)->getToken()) {

                return $this->respond('tymon.jwt.absent', 'token_not_provided', 400);
            }
```

For example, I want to return a custom message when token is not provided.

```
if (! $token = $this->auth->setRequest($request)->getToken()) {

            return my_custom_message;
        }
```

since I cannot make changes directly on this file, how should I create a custom class to override vendor's GetUserFromToken.php ?

Please describe required steps in detail if possible. Thanks.

update#2

Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [

    'jwt.auth' => \App\Http\override\MyGetUserFromToken::class,
```

I created GetUserFromToken.php in below directory.
myProject\app\Http\override\MyGetUserFromToken.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\Middleware;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken;

class MyGetUserFromToken extends GetUserFromToken
{
    public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
    {
        if (! $token = $this->auth->setRequest($request)->getToken()) {
            return my_custom_message;
        }
```

Comment: Since it is simply a middleware, you should just be able to extend this class `class MyGetUserFromToken extends GetUserFromToken` and list this class in Kernel.php as middleware. Like this `'jwt.auth'          => App\MyGetUserFromToken::class,`

Comment: Hi, I get "ReflectionException in Container.php line 734:
Class App\Http\override\MyGetUserFromToken does not exist" after I made update#2. Any idea what causing this problem ?

Comment: Simply check that the file does really exist and that there are no typos. Including usage of capital letters. For example Override vs override?

Comment: I deleted App\Http\override\MyGetUserFromToken and re-create it again using php artisan make:middleware, now it is working. I am not sure what I did wrong but thanks for your support.

Comment: It might have simply been a case of running `composer dump-autoload` which I think Laravel automatically runs if you create classes with Artisan. Since you found the comments useful I also added the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is simply a middleware, you should just be able to extend this class:

```
class MyGetUserFromToken extends GetUserFromToken
```

and list this class in `Kernel.php` as middleware. Like this:

```
'jwt.auth' => App\MyGetUserFromToken::class
```