# Laravel jwt.auth retrieve token from Body

Tags: php, laravel-5, jwt, laravel-middleware

I want to be able to retrieve the token from the http_request_body as for annoying reasons where I need to send the data from, the token is too long to send as part of the query string, and they don't accept sending headers.

Anyway, I've managed to edit the jwt.auth GetUserFromToken middleware to the following:

```
if (! $token = $this->auth->setRequest($request)->getToken()) {
    if(! $token = $request->get('token') ) {
        return $this->respond('tymon.jwt.absent', 'token_not_provided', 400);
    }
}
```

This works, but I am wondering if there is a better way that would be more permanent?
Obviously when I deploy or the package is updated this will be over-ridden.

Is there a way to extend to extend or over-ride this class from within my app, rather than directly in the vendor Middleware?

Thanks!

Comment: you can check this link how to override the vendor route with package

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832146/can-i-use-laravel-5-middleware-to-allow-packages-to-override-app-routes

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, usually when something is too long to send as a query string you send it via post which would send it in the request body, but in that case `$request->get("token")` should still work as though the token was in the query string.

Comment: @apokryfos think you miss understood, the modification does work, the question was really around how to make the modification permanent

Comment: You can just override this class in your own middleware and set your overriding middleware in the middleware stack instead of the default one. That's what Laravel also does with the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware as an example.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Moeen Basra @apokryfos and this [How to override vendor class file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43328442/how-to-override-vendor-class-file)

Managed to extend the Middleware so that it overrides the existing Class and won't be impacted when the app is deployed or the package updated.

Added MyGetUserFromToken.php

```
namespace App\Overrides\Tymon;

use Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken;

class MyGetUserFromToken extends GetUserFromToken {
```

And then in the Kernel

```
//use Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken;
use App\Overrides\Tymon\MyGetUserFromToken;

...

'jwt.auth' => MyGetUserFromToken::class,
```

Hopefully this will then help others also.